# SPL TOKEN recognized as NFT instead of a regular token

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, spl, spl-associated-token-account, spl-token-cli

I created a spl-token using strata protocol and it is being recognized as NFT on my wallet, even on solscan it is not showing similar to any other token.

I found that maybe i would need to pull a request here: https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list
But that repository has been archived by the owner before Nov 9, 2022 and is now read-only.

My issue is, even if i create an SPL-TOKEN using spl-token-cli, how can i add metadata to it? ( Name, Description, Image, Decimals, etc.)

I would rather prefer to update the token i already created using strata protocol because it is already distributed by some people, otherwise i would need to burn that one, and airdrop the new one,etc.

Let me know if im missing something

Answer (score 1):

Wallets will treat unknown tokens in all sorts of different ways, so one wallet calling it an NFT just means that it corresponds to a few of their criteria, so don't worry about that too much.

You're correct that the token list is deprecated and should not be used. In its place, the recommendation is to use the Metaplex Token Metadata program to add information about your token, assuming that you still have control over the mint authority.

You can learn more about it at https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/